# Strange block texture background in imagemagick conversion frin PDF to JPG

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using this command to convert PDF to JPG:

```
exec("convert -scale 772x1000 -density 150 -trim \"".$toc_path.$filename."[0]\" -background white -flatten -quality 100 \"".$img_path. "covers/". $img_filename ."\"");
```

Random Fuzzy B & W background gets converted in to huge squares:

[image: Original PDF]

[image: Result of converstion]

Comment: Just an untested idea... try omitting the `-scale` parameter altogether and experimenting with different densities to control the size.

Comment: Maybe try omitting `-flatten` too.

Comment: looks like density was the answer, density below 300 was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to increase the density up to 300, and then scale down to whatever size you you like eg:

```
convert -scale 772x1000 -density 300 -trim \"".$toc_path.$filename."[0]\" -background white -flatten -quality 80 \"".$img_path. "covers/". $img_filename ."\"");
```

@ density 75 with no scale, size = 1.3mb - smaller blocks looked bad

@ density 150 with no scale size = 2.0mb = large blocks looked bad

@ density 300 with no scale size = 2.4mb = no blocks looked like original

@ density 300 with scale to 1000 lines = 170kb = no blocks looked like original